# Sending data to a parent activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

how can I send data from chlid activity to a parent activity? I'm using this:
In child activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("data", data);
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

And in parent activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    data= (ClientBluetooth)data.getSerializableExtra("data");

   }
}
```

But i have an error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

You forgot to set the intent, resulting in a null intent in the parent activity. Do this:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```